# How to format my usb stick when it doesn't allow me to format?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Cant use my usb stick

I tried using nautilus formatting the usb, I get: "Error formatting volume"
I tried using fdisk and even the dd command but nothing works.

If I put the usb in my laptop in windows, after a moment it even disappears from This PC (in ubuntu it does stay visible in nautilus).

There are a few files on my usb, I can't delete them either (I get "You don't have sufficient permissions to delete the file ... ".

What are the options to fix my usb stick?

**EDIT**:
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt. Automatically removing dirty bit. Boot sector contents: ...
Then it gives an error that it can't find /dev/sdb so whenever performing some operation on the usb, it will eventually be like windows where you can't see the usb in nautilus anymore.

**Minimum size is 41mb??**

[Details of gdb formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MeMi.png)

Comment: have you read [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/format-usb-drive-sd-card-ubuntu/)?

Comment: Analyze the USB stick according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if the hardware is still good, fix the partition table and file system with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: @User24601 I've tried it with gparted as well, no luck there. I've tried again and it says: "Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb"

Comment: is the stick hard locked (small tab on the side)?

Comment: @User24601 No, I am using now Check and repair function of gparted so lets see...

Comment: @sudodus  I've edited the question, it says minimum size 41mb???

Comment: Did you analyze the results according to the link in my first comment? -- Dirty bit means that the file system is (more or less) corrupted. This should not prevent formatting. If the hardware is not damaged, it should work to wipe the first mibibyte of the drive and then format it. This can be done easily with mkusb (and also with other tools, but maybe not as easily). If you reboot the computer, install mkusb and try to 'restore to a Standard storage device' you should succeed. If it fails, the drive hardware is probably damaged (an internal damage in the USB stick's electronic system).

Comment: @sudodus yes and mkusb-dus didn't work either, after a while it says it can't find /dev/sdb, it seems that there is something wrong with the usb since it says the partition starts from 41mb, perhaps repartitioning tool?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think the USB stick is damaged beyond repair.

Answer (score 0):

This stack is more about problems when writing to USB sticks.

- [How to fix read-only usb drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004827/how-to-fix-read-only-usb-drive)

Do not rule out the defective scenario for too long, it will save you a lot of time, maybe...

Comment: I've edited the question, it says minimum size 41mb???

Comment: Sorry, I am currently in no country with an outdated smartphone, but in the first step I would really rule out that the stick is not defective. Try to read a block with dd and then write again. If the writing is unsuccessful, then for me that would be the sign of a defective medium. If medium is ok, next steps will be more accurate.